# Copying a Column: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected. DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to copy a column from one table to another. using the Distinct or Related.

```
Total Basket = DISTINCT(Sales[Total Basket])
```

Error: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

```
Total Basket = RELATED(Sales[Total Basket])
```

Error: The column 'Sales[Total Basket]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.

Comment: Can you show some sample date from both tables?

Answer (score 1):

- The DISTINCT() function returns a table, so it can only be used in a **calculated table** expression, not in a **calculated column** nor a **measure**. This is why you are getting the first error message.
- The RELATED() function returns a scalar, but it requires a row context, so it can only be used in a **calculated column**, not a **measure**
- The second error message indicates, that you are either using it wrongly in a **measure**, or in a **calculated column**, but on the one-side of a one-to-many relationship, which is also not allowed.